# Getting Restful Json response with slashes

Tags: java, json, rest

I Have a `Restful webservice` application Ex: `SampleApp`

In this application I have `POST` and `GET` `APIs`.

Inside `DB` I have a table structure as follows

```
Table : SampleTable
Column1: Id(INT)
Column2: data(blob)
```

I have a model as follows

```
class SampleModel{
    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    // setters and getters
}
```

Using `POST` API, I am inserting data into `DB` while inserting I am converting `SampleModel` object to `json string` as follows

```
String data = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(sampleModleObject);
// here I have code to insert data into DB
```

Up to here its working as expected.

Now I am fetching data from DB for `GET` API

```
// code for select query we got the ROW object because I am using cassandra as DB
ByteBuffer buffer = row.getBytes("data");
String sampleString = new String(buffer.array(), "UTF-8");
Logger.info("Sample Object {}", sampleString); // here I am not getting any slashes in the response 
// here I can use ObjectMapper and then convert sampleString to SampleModel object but I should not do it
Response.entity(sampleString).build;
```

When I execute above functionality using an API call Ex: `/sampleapp/sample` then in the browser I am seeing slashes in the response as below

```
{\"fname\":\"firstName\",\"lname\":\"lastname\"}
```

Comment: this is JSON string first convert it into the JSON object.

Comment: Tried with JSON object also but it didn't work

Comment: check in post man how it is giving you response

Comment: because your json is not valid which you have posted it is string format ask your api developer to send you object instead of string

Comment: `Javax.ws.rs.core.Response` object

Comment: @Sat I meant the server side code of `GET` method

Comment: Yeah thats what I am saying... its something like
`public Response getData(){ //code  return Response.entity(sampleString).build;}`

Comment: Could you check if the Content-Type of the response is application/json, if not, the browser will interpret the response as string and will use the backslashes as escape characters. Also, I am curious how did you map `SampleModel` to `SampleTable`?

Comment: Content-Type is `application/jon` only.. I used normal cassandra insertion query to insert data into `SampleTable`